# How to bind pallet objects with mxgraph diagrams?

Tags: javascript, angular, mxgraph

I am new to mxgraph. I am using angular 4. In this, pallet is in one component,  diagram is in another component. So I need to drop objects from pallet to diagram. But objects are not dropping into canvas. 
Can anyone one help me how to connect pallet and diagram in angular 4?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be more specific about your issue and what you tried and what didn't work. But I guarantee this is possible because I have done it in my app (angular 1)

I use mxUtils.makeDraggable to make the element draggable and it works just fine

Comment: Have you Passed referrence of Diagram graph to pallete? Or For Pallete you have created new graph Object? Can you send me your Angular Sample to me?

Comment: You need to pass the same graph as a variable! Don't have time to extract the code; but it's really only using makeDraggable with the mxGraph instance stored in a rootScope variable